# XML ParseError for letter?

Tags: python, xml

While attempting to parse some very large XML, I ran into a parsing error. I was able to narrow down that the issue was somewhere in the `writeup` tag and when I re-ran my code with just that section, it produced the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "path\to\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 310
```

When I looked at line 1, column 310 in Atom there's just a `N` which is not a forbidden character in XML. Why is this issue popping up and how can I fix it?

Code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
xml = """<writeup>&lt;p&gt;sVw*f4FgT9`|wXNz!x)McB})KDh*0O"47BKR;G4F3]p3!-?n!\'%_sP:3WuGw44yTGF""Mf=8d34:Pb0pCZF](d%+(V\'M3-i*Dr:#sS/o*[_Z$"8%F*H6_lr&amp;gt;I#lmd/RIUskV9@Ba\\poJ&amp;lt;GVG]5CVIeJJytI7]q{pJQLF/&amp;amp;N:kYrJ^3s"aCdHupx@_/Ool9qfo1.?$cdd&amp;gt;u{Xi|yQyPahZ88ayU;DX[eDr9p?G)"*I^VG4xvJjZDCTUr1@qE6e=By_^YINk!\x02~eU3v1(pgU-\\"(*)[dg#}cVG&amp;gt;2b=P-uH9z?fOS9amy\'e~ZO,2?,^cAWpt;jo+`p/D`B&amp;gt;&amp;gt;NLDqhN~&amp;lt;"=_"DU0V^kqDTN=7EWZL|ax&amp;amp;7dn&amp;gt;]u1C)-[}~wuS",je`OOGIwT1g.jSe:3!tn^E2z!|4)B+rUV@6&amp;amp;~,(iv,A%`W_\')E"kdD({ppNuPts%P%/Gi;`Hx-P/}WX(\\&amp;amp;N2[pSy=\'9D1b?XNKG*E.@v3riX]Dq@8EEt;OA3:Uav3\'2^\\r;|Ck75}inlV)TrTFGgsI{wLx/KrmehxiwK*9^"UGa8DAV?wd~\\)gP4!r}(Y0Sx^ssxS^6zx4)#XS7|.bxFbV`t\\D,w\\YqW+&amp;amp;%v)+&amp;amp;fFtl]g28M61m34gD=|w{~OmjKbJr1QOI7I%]X\'m*r-p=sUeE.L-"rXR`L&amp;gt;,nz{%\';3VY:aAKQa~ngm"Sx$3RxB!AH$O^t1&amp;lt;9~t}ujaZ}D2\'*\\b}gGMBg4,`m9WL0Eo&lt;/p&gt;</writeup>"""
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

Comment: That string you're trying to parse here looks like it was designed to choke lxml to death ... are you sure it should look like this?

Comment: @meissner_ It's how it looks in Elasticsearch where it's being pulled from. I didn't create the string, it's from a separate system, but yes it is--unfortunately--supposed to look like that.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: @DanielHaley Apologies, I was off for the weekend and the whole process took quite a while to verify because of my application but it looks like it fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your assistance! I've accepted the answer.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad my answer helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `\x02` in the string. Python thinks that is an ASCII hex character.

Try making your string a raw string by prefixing the string with "r". This will make `\` a literal character instead of an escape character.

Example...

```
xml = r"""<writeup>&lt;p&gt;sVw*f4FgT9`|wXNz!x)McB})KDh*0O"47BKR;G4F3]p3!-?n!\'%_sP:3WuGw44yTGF""Mf=8d34:Pb0pCZF](d%+(V\'M3-i*Dr:#sS/o*[_Z$"8%F*H6_lr&amp;gt;I#lmd/RIUskV9@Ba\\poJ&amp;lt;GVG]5CVIeJJytI7]q{pJQLF/&amp;amp;N:kYrJ^3s"aCdHupx@_/Ool9qfo1.?$cdd&amp;gt;u{Xi|yQyPahZ88ayU;DX[eDr9p?G)"*I^VG4xvJjZDCTUr1@qE6e=By_^YINk!\x02~eU3v1(pgU-\\"(*)[dg#}cVG&amp;gt;2b=P-uH9z?fOS9amy\'e~ZO,2?,^cAWpt;jo+`p/D`B&amp;gt;&amp;gt;NLDqhN~&amp;lt;"=_"DU0V^kqDTN=7EWZL|ax&amp;amp;7dn&amp;gt;]u1C)-[}~wuS",je`OOGIwT1g.jSe:3!tn^E2z!|4)B+rUV@6&amp;amp;~,(iv,A%`W_\')E"kdD({ppNuPts%P%/Gi;`Hx-P/}WX(\\&amp;amp;N2[pSy=\'9D1b?XNKG*E.@v3riX]Dq@8EEt;OA3:Uav3\'2^\\r;|Ck75}inlV)TrTFGgsI{wLx/KrmehxiwK*9^"UGa8DAV?wd~\\)gP4!r}(Y0Sx^ssxS^6zx4)#XS7|.bxFbV`t\\D,w\\YqW+&amp;amp;%v)+&amp;amp;fFtl]g28M61m34gD=|w{~OmjKbJr1QOI7I%]X\'m*r-p=sUeE.L-"rXR`L&amp;gt;,nz{%\';3VY:aAKQa~ngm"Sx$3RxB!AH$O^t1&amp;lt;9~t}ujaZ}D2\'*\\b}gGMBg4,`m9WL0Eo&lt;/p&gt;</writeup>"""
```

In your actual code, if you're getting the XML as a string from an outside source, try encoding the string with `.encode("unicode-escape")`

```
root = etree.fromstring(xml.encode("unicode-escape"))
```